# Group by and get the last row

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

When I used the

```
SELECT * FROM reports WHERE staff='$username' GROUP BY taskid
```

on my query, I get a result of the first row from that group.

What do I need to add to get the result from the last row of that group?

last row means having id greater than the other row from that group.

I tried adding

```
ORDER BY id DESC
```

or

```
ORDER BY id
```

but it did not return the intended result.

Comment: why are you using GROUP BY here?

Comment: I used group by coz I know that it will return just one row... and that's what I want :)

Comment: you should be using the LIMIT clause to specify the amount of rows returned. GROUP BY is for perfoming functions on groups which you dont seem to need

Answer (score 1):

You are using a group by function without any aggregate functions. You probably want to do an order by instead (No group by in the query):

```
SELECT * FROM reports WHERE staff='$username' order BY taskid desc;
```

Group By functions are commonly used when you want to use an aggregate function on a particular column (such as get an average row value, or a sum) and the like. If you are not using any aggregate function, then using Group By will not do anything.

If you only want to get one row from the query you can add a limit clause like this:

```
SELECT * FROM reports WHERE staff='$username' order BY taskid desc limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want the "last" row **per group**, then you need to specify which field defines uniqueness (i.e. what you mean by "first/last row") and then isolate those rows in a subquery.

e.g.

this gets you the max(id) for each group

```
SELECT taskid, max(id) as max_id FROM reports 
WHERE staff ='$username' 
GROUP BY taskid
```

and this gets the entire row(s):

```
select * from reports where id 
in
(
    SELECT max(id) as max_id FROM reports 
    WHERE staff='$username' 
    GROUP BY taskid
) x
```

This of course assumes that id is unique and assigned in ascending order and that therefore max(id) indicates the last row per group.

Alternatively you could rewrite this using a join:

```
select * from reports r
inner join
(
    SELECT max(id) as max_id FROM reports 
    WHERE staff='$username' 
    GROUP BY taskid
) x
on r.id = x.max_id
```