# Mysql group by and prefered field = 1 in join table

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, inner-join

I have workshops that have manufacturers, one workshop can have many manufacturers, but only one official. I want to get all workshops that have manufacturer 22 but if they have same vat only get workshop who manufacturer is offical

I have 2 tables, first workshop

```
id | name          | vat
-------------------------
 1 | name 1        | B12
 2 | name 2        | B12
 3 | name 3        | B12
 4 | name 4        | E98
 5 | name 5        | A99
```

second workshop_manufacturer

```
id | workshop_id | manufacturer_id  | official
----------------------------------------------
 1 | 1           | 22               | 0               
 2 | 2           | 22               | 0
 3 | 3           | 22               | 1
 4 | 4           | 22               | 0
 5 | 5           | 22               | 1
 5 | 5           | 23               | 0
 5 | 5           | 24               | 0
```

I want to get unique workshops (group by vat) but I want to get the official one (official=1) if there are many workshop with same vat who work with this manufacturer.

If I do this query:

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.* FROM workshop t1
INNER JOIN workshop_manufacturer t2 ON t1.id=t2.workshop_id
WHERE t2.manufacturer.id = 22
GROUP bY t1.vat
```

I get this:

```
id | name    | vat  | official | manufacturer_id 
-----------------------------------------------
 1 | name 1  | B12  | 0       | 22
 4 | name 4  | E98  | 0       | 22
 5 | name 5  | A99  | 1       | 22
```

and I want this:

```
id | name    | vat  | official | manufacturer_id 
-----------------------------------------------
 3 | name 3  | B12  | 1      | 22
 4 | name 4  | E98  | 0      | 22
 5 | name 5  | A99  | 1      | 22
```

All the workshops who are official and non official but giving priority that ones who are official

Comment: check this link, you might get some insight how group by work
[php mysql GROUP BY … get the last occurence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368974/php-mysql-group-by-get-the-last-occurence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a prioritization, not an aggregation.  But it is rather complicated.

The following gets the ids for the workshops for each "vat":

```
select w.vat, max(case when w.official = 1 then w.id end) as official_id,
       max(w.id) as max_id
from workshop_manufacturer wm join
     workshop w
     on w.id = wm.workshop_id
group by w.vat;
```

There are two ids, one if `official` is available, and another for the maximum id.

You can now use this in a `join` to get the rest of the fields:

```
select w.workshop_id, w.name, w.vat,
       (official_id is not null) as official
from (select w.vat, max(case when w.official = 1 then w.id end) as official_id,
             max(w.id) as max_id
      from workshop_manufacturer wm join
           workshop w
           on w.id = wm.workshop_id
      group by w.vat
     ) v join
     workshop w
     on w.id = coalesce(official_id, max_id);
```

Comment: With this query I am getting only one result. And I want to get all workshops. I have edited my question with more information.

Comment: @h3llr4iser . . . It was missing the `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.* FROM workshop t1
INNER JOIN workshop_manufacturer t2 ON t1.id=t2.workshop_id 
GROUP bY t1.vat having t2.official = 1
```

Comment: Here i am getting only official ones but I need also who are not official